# Redis cannot bind a specific ip address?

Tags: firewall, tcp, django, ufw, redis

I'm new to redis, but I want to set one up on my Raspberry Pi 4 (RP) for using it in a Django application (with celery).

On my RP I have installed a firewall, `ufw`, and allowed incomming traffic from my PC's IP on port 6379 (redis port).

I have then editted my `redis.config` on RP with

```
bind 192...... #The IP address for my pc
```

But now the redis-server wont start. The log writes:

```
Could not create server TCP listening socket 192....:6379 bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

If I bind `0.0.0.0` it works fine, and I can access the server from my local PC.

As far as I understand, the "bind" is like an "allow connections from this ip"but I might've misunderstood it.

Any ideas on what that error setting "means"? Is it a firewall issue? Do I miss something in my `redis.config`?.

Comment: Do not redact [RFC1918](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)-IP's. They won't reveal anything anyway, and redacting may hide problems.

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I understand, the "bind" is like an "allow connections from this ip"but I might've misunderstood it.

You have. The [configuration file for redis is fairly self documenting](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/7.0/redis.conf):

> ```
> # By default, if no "bind" configuration directive is specified, Redis listens
> # for connections from all available network interfaces on the host machine.
> # It is possible to listen to just one or multiple selected interfaces using
> # the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one or more IP addresses.
> # Each address can be prefixed by "-", which means that redis will not fail to
> # start if the address is not available. Being not available only refers to
> # addresses that does not correspond to any network interface. Addresses that
> # are already in use will always fail, and unsupported protocols will always BE
> # silently skipped.
> ```

The bind directive tells redis *which* network interfaces to listen to, not which IP's you should accept connections from. `0.0.0.0` means all available network interfaces.

Comment: Not for being rude, but how does that help me solving the issue?

Comment: I might've misunderstood your explanation

Comment: `bind` is not where it accepts connections from. It's what IP's it will reply *from*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows firewall to restrict connection to the REDIS port.
https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2984/How-to-configure-the-Windows-Firewall-to-allow-only-specific-IP-Address-to-connect-your-ports.html